# Set associative vs fully associative cache

Tags: memory

If I have a 4-way set associative cache that has 8 cache lines, how many sets of lines would there be?

-I would say 4 sets of lines (1 set of lines per way, each set containing 2 lines)

And if I take that 4 way set associative cache and transform it to a fully associative cache, how many sets of lines would there be?

-I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Note that that in an n-way associative cache, each set contains n lines. I'm also not sure what you mean by "1 set of lines per way."

A fully associative cache is not partitioned according to set.

There are very good resources on this topic (and others) available online. It may be a good idea to make use of them.